# Delete unused indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance

I run this query for check if there are some unused indexes in my DataBase.

```
select 
    t.tablename AS "relation",
    indexname,
    c.reltuples AS num_rows,
    pg_relation_size(quote_ident(t.tablename)::text) AS table_size,
    pg_relation_size(quote_ident(indexrelname)::text) AS index_size,
    idx_scan AS number_of_scans,
    idx_tup_read AS tuples_read,
    idx_tup_fetch AS tuples_fetched
FROM pg_tables t
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class c ON t.tablename=c.relname
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( SELECT c.relname AS ctablename, ipg.relname AS indexname, x.indnatts AS number_of_columns, psai.idx_scan, idx_tup_read, idx_tup_fetch, indexrelname, indisunique FROM pg_index x
           JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = x.indrelid
           JOIN pg_class ipg ON ipg.oid = x.indexrelid
           JOIN pg_stat_all_indexes psai ON x.indexrelid = psai.indexrelid )
    AS foo
    ON t.tablename = foo.ctablename
WHERE t.schemaname='public'
and idx_scan = 0
ORDER BY 
--1,2
--6
5 desc
;
```

And I got a lot of rows where those fields are all zero:

```
number_of_scans,
tuples_read,
tuples_fetched
```

Is that mean that I can drop them? Is there a chance that that Metadata is out-of-date? How can I check it?

I'm using Postgres with version 9.6

Comment: Some unique indexes might never be used for queries - but you can not drop them without compromising your data integrity

Comment: I know.  But in case I dont want to apply the data integrity that way..

Answer (score 6):

Your query misses some uses of indexes that do not require them to be scanned:

- they enforce primary key, unique and exclusion constraints
- they influence statistics collection (for “expression indexes”)

Here is my gold standard query from [my blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes):

```
SELECT s.schemaname,
       s.relname AS tablename,
       s.indexrelname AS indexname,
       pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) AS index_size
FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_indexes s
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON s.indexrelid = i.indexrelid
WHERE s.idx_scan = 0      -- has never been scanned
  AND 0 <>ALL (i.indkey)  -- no index column is an expression
  AND NOT EXISTS          -- does not enforce a constraint
         (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
          WHERE c.conindid = s.indexrelid)
ORDER BY pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) DESC;
```

Anything that shows up there has not been used since the statistics have been reset and can be safely dropped.

There are a few caveats:

- statistics collection must run (look for the “statistics collector” process and see if you have warnings about “stale statistics” in the log)
- run the query against your production database
- if your program is running at many sites, try it on all of them (different users have different usage patterns)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you can delete them, however you should make sure your query runs after a typical workload. That is, are there some indexes that show no usage in this query only used during certain times when specialized queries run? Month-end reporting, weekly runs, etc? We ran into this a couple of times - several large indexes didn't get used during the day but supported month-end summaries.

Comment: If they used in month-end summaries,  why there are zeroes?

Comment: Some database engines reset these stats when the server is restarted. I think it is possible that, mid-month, stats for end-of-month or otherwise not-used-today indexes might show a usage count of zero. Worth looking into either way.